# Asp.net validators validate Disabled control

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, c#-4.0

I have a `Panel` control that contains some control such as text boxes.I want to use asp.net validators to validate text boxes.But if `Panle` is disabled then text boxes become disabled but validators such as `RequiredFieldValidator` validate disabled text box.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Enabled="false">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
        ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="TextBox2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</asp:Panel>
```

How I can set for validators that don't validate disabled controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if some control is disabled you can set its  property `CausesValidation="False"`

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server"
  Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:Button>
```

**EDITED**

can you do this way

```
if (!panel.Enabled)
{
    RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;// disable your all validators
}
```

Comment: No no.I have some panel with control inside them.according some condition I enable and disable them.I want to validate `Enabled` panel's controls

Comment: you can disable all the validators of respected controls, see my edited answer

Comment: this is a solution but is not exist another better way?

Comment: other thing is i told you already set `CausesValidation` to false

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in **Page_Load()**

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = panel.Enabled;
```